# Get data from database with two conditions in one list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to this. I have a (sqlite3, but with ActiveRecord it doesn't matter) table called Messages and a model called Message. I want to find all messages in database that have user_id or reciever_id equal to the object user and his attribute id (for short user.id). I know it's probably just one simple line of code, but I wanna do it the right "rails" way and I don't have much experience with this.

I'm using Rails 3. Thanks for any help.

Cheers

Comment: This looks trivial as you suspect, but it would help if you posted what your models currently look like.

Comment: I don't know. It probably won't. I just don't know what to write in @messages = Message.find(here, :limit => 10), if it can be done like @messages = Message.find(:all, :conditions => {:user_id => ? OR :reciever_id => ?, user.id, user.id}, :limit => 10) or @messages = Message.find(:all, :conditions => [:user_id => user.id, :reciever_id => user.id], :limit => 10) and if this is the proper way to do it or I should use something like where method or something. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that what you will want this relationship in many places in your code, and actually this represents a fundamental part of your application's design.

Conceptually a 'message' belongs to a 'sender' and also to a 'receiver'. In reverse, a 'user' has many messages that she has sent, and many messages that she has received.

in the Message model, add the following

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => "User"
```

in the User model, add the following

```
has_many :messages
has_many :sent_or_received_messages, :class_name => "Message", :conditions => ["user_id = ? OR receiver_id = ?", id, id])
```

Now you can do this:

```
my_user.messages # all of the messages the user has sent
my_message.user # the user who sent the message
my_message.receiver # the user who received the message
my_user.sent_or_received_messages # all messages where the user was a sender or a receiver
```

Comment: That "middle" code would do my thing the easiest and the most accessible way. Thanks.

Comment: One more question. If I want to order those messages descending by created_at, can I write something like has_many :sent_or_received_messages, :class_name => "Message", :conditions => ["user_id = ? OR receiver_id = ?", id, id]) :order => "created_at DESC" ? Thanks for info. I'll look up for some tutorial on rails working with SQL conditions, really need to do that.

Comment: Yep - that should work. Remember there is a distinction between ActiveRecord (the Object Relational Mapper) and Rails - it just so happens you are using AR (the default), but you could use one of many others. So if you are googling, also look for ActiveRecord documentation. No problem.

Comment: Sorry, let's take a step back.. has_many :sent_or_received_messages, :class_name => "Message", :conditions => ["user_id = ? OR receiver_id = ?", id, id] isn't working for me. I'm getting NameError: undefined local variable or method `id' for #<Class:0x00000101b33678> on that line. Don't know what could be wrong. Any idea?

Comment: ad) That's happening when user = User.find_by_id(1), don't know it's relevant information or not.

Comment: Same problem. I'll try to write an action user.sent_or_received_messages, not to get to that via :has many. That should work.

Comment: Well I think it must be @id. Seems to be at least working, but I get the empty field back, I'll check the database.

Comment: Well, I take it back, it doesn't work. Non of it. No id on User object is yet initialized in the time when it reaches this :has_many line I think. The only way is probably just via an action, but thanks anyway for try. At least I know how to write that condition =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you mean a user `has_many :messages`....

```
# assuming you are looking for a particular user
Message.where(['user_id=? OR receiver_id=?', user.id, user.id])
```